# Apache Camel EJB Timeout

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel to route the request to EJB service, but i would like to know how can i set timeout time?

If it is an HTTP service, Camel HTTP component has options to set timeout but not EJB service.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a SEDA endpoint before your EJB endpoint; SEDA handles timeout.

Comment: If i am not wrong the end point below `<endpoint id="com__dbs__testapp__EJB_Req" uri="ejb:ejb/MappedEJBModule_jar/MappedEJBModule.jar/RemoteEmployeeBean#com.iexceed.study.ejb.employee.RemoteEmployee?method=receiveEmployee"/>` has to be modified to `<endpoint id="com__dbs__testapp__EJB_Req" uri="seda:ejb:ejb/MappedEJBModule_jar/MappedEJBModule.jar/RemoteEmployeeBean#com.iexceed.study.ejb.employee.RemoteEmployee?method=receiveEmployee"/>`